# Adding "A1,A2,A3.." to "B1,B2,B3.." Then Row "A" resets value to Zero

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2003

I am currently trying to add a script into excel. excuse my terminology, I am not that hot with programming!

I do all of my accounting on excel 2003, and I would like to be able to add the value of say cells `f6` to `f27` to the cells `e6` to `e27`, respectively. The thing is, I want the value of the "f" column to reset every time.

So far I have found this code, which works if I copy and paste it into VBA. but it only allows  me to use it on one row:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target.Address = Range("f7").Address Then
        Range("e7") = Range("e7") + Range("f7")
        Range("f7").ClearContents
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

would somebody be kind enough to explain how I can edit this to do the same through all of my desired cells? I have tried adding Range("f7",[f8],[f9] etc.. but i am really beyond my knowledge.

Comment: Please [edit] the title of your question to something that edescribes the problem you're having. You've included that it's about Excel and VBA in your tags, and it's clear you need help or you wouldn't be asking here, which means there is zero meaningful content in the title as it is now. Your title should indicate something about the problem, and should be useful to future readers finding it in a search result.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to define the range which is supposed to be "caught"; that is, define the range you want to track for changes. I found an example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775%28v=office.15%29.aspx). Then, simply add the values to the other cell:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range)
    Dim r as Range ' The range you'll track for changes
    Set r = Range("F2:F27")

    ' If the changed cell is not in the tracked range, then exit the procedure
    ' (in other words, if the intersection between target and r is empty)
    If Intersect(Target, r) Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        ' Now, if the changed cell is in the range, then update the required value:
        Cells(Target.Row, 5).Value = Cells(Target.Row, 5).Value + Target.Value
        ' ----------------^
        ' Column 5 = 
        '       column "E"

        ' Clear the changed cell
        Target.ClearContents
    End if
End Sub
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi. Thanks so much for your reply. Sorry, im really not great at this. I interpreted that i should type this into the VBA??    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Range("F2:F27")
 If Intersect(Target, r) Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
    Cells(Target.Row, 5).Value = Cells(Target.Row, 5).Value + Target.Value
       Target.ClearContents
    End If
End Sub

Comment: thanks so much. just needed to turn off macro security!

Comment: @RhysDavies Happy to help. By the way, if you find this useful, up-vote it and/or accept it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Intersect(Target, Range("B1:B5,F6:F27")) Then 'U can define any other range   
        Target.Offset(0, -1) = Target.Offset(0, -1).Value + Target.Value ' Target.Offset(0,-1) refer to cell one column before the changed cell column.
        'OR: Cells(Target.row, 5) = Cells(Target.row, 5).Value + Target.Value '  Where the 5 refer to column E
        Target.ClearContents
    End If

ErrHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```